# 96 Ranger. I replaced the clutch. Now it won't go into gear

Tags: ford, clutch, manual-transmission, ranger

I'm no mechanic and I'm stuck.

I've got a 1996 2.3L Ford Ranger.  I replaced The clutch disk, pressure plate, pilot bearing, and release bearing.  I then got the transmission put back into place.  Once I attached the shifter knob I noticed that I can't put the transmission into any gear with the engine off.  I then attached the slave cylinder and attempted to engage the clutch and shift.  Still no avail.  If I depress the clutch it is firm and if and look through the dust cover underneath I can see that the bearing is moving about an inch or so.

Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you go through the gears with the engine running?

Comment: You might need to bleed the slave cylinder.

Comment: @Moab - How would bleeding the hydraulics make any difference if the transmission won't go into gear *without the engine running*?

Comment: I figured it out.  I had has taken the shifter out while it was in gear.  I took a flat head and put the transmission into neutral.  Problem shoved.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Best thing it to just answer your own question here in the box below.  Include photos's if you have them.  That really helps anybody else who may have a similiar problem in the future.  Nice work on figuring this out.

Comment: @Matthew.Paul.P  I see you deleted your answer.  Did that not solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  I had has taken the shifter out while it was in gear.  I took a flat head and put the transmission into neutral.  Problem shoved.  Thanks everyone!